# How react server will contact node server through private IP

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

## I have 3 ec2 Instance on aws

- React Server
- Node Server
- MongoDB Server

Now I would like to connect My React Server to Node server through Private IP. In short If I call my Node server through Public IP it will not response(For Security purpose).

Currently My React server will communicate with Node Server through Public IP. If I call My node server through public IP it will respond(Which I don't want to happen)

I helped with this link but not getting luck to implement https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-centos-7

I also attached the private ip on my node server and call my node server through react through private ip

```
  app.listen(app.get('port'), "xxx.xx.xx.xx",function(){
    console.log('Server Started on Port '+app.get('port'));
  });
```

I was able to connect my Mongo Server through Private IP through Node server.

On My Mongo Server aws inbound rules: I allow node server private ip, similarly on my node server, I allow react server private ip.

Is there anyone who can tell me how to fix this issue as personally our backend server will not exposed outside the world (as per my opinion). Rest all experts give me some guidance so that I will fix this problem.

#### Any Help/Suggestion is really appreciated

### Question Update

On my Node server Inbound Rules, I allow React Server Private IP so that only react server makes the connection with Node.

After this I go to React server and open the terminal and type command

```
curl http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:3000 (i.e my node private IP)
```

It will response but when on code where I am connecting backend request I update the IP from public ip to private IP then it will not responsed. I am getting stucked with this.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a AWS-VPC (Virtual Private Cloud). The architecture for your VPC should contain atleast 1 public and 1 private subnet. Put all your application instance in private subnet and they will be able to talk to each other. Put a reverse proxy in Public subnet and let the node server serve as a backend to it. This is how you can make sure you keep the architecture of your application clean.
Also VPC will help you create a Highly available setup if you create 2 public and 2 private subnets.

Comment: really appreciate for your valuable suggestion.